# Default Gateway Query/Confusion

Tags: networking, router, vmware-workstation

I have VMware workstation 15.X and set up the following networks set up via the network editor:

VMware workstations on a Vmware Network (Vmnet). The ip subnet of

10.3.3.0.

VMware workstations on a Vmware Network (Vmnet). The ip subnet of

10.2.2.0

VMware workstations on a Vmware Network (Vmnet). The ip subnet of

10.1.1.0.

Home DSL router Address 10.0.0.138 ( This is the default gateway for my home lan)

I've Installed a Freesco router Vm http://www.freesco.org/ as one of the VM's on the management LAN (10.0.0.X)

The gateway of the Freesco Router itself is 10.0.0.138 and has the main nic on the 10.0.0.X Lan.

I have set up/added the 10.3.3.0 LAN on the Freesco Router and set it up as DHCP and a given it a range.

The VM’s connected on the 10.3.3.0 Lan receive the DHCP allocated IP addresses within the Range of the Freesco router DHCP Scope. But the DG is 10.0.0.138. I’m just concerned that this is not correct? how are the isolated 10.3.3.0 VM's even seeing the 10.0.0.138 DG? Shouldn’t the IP address of the Freesco Router (10.3.3.10 which I statically allocated) be the default gateway?is the Freesco virtual device acting only in the capacity of a DHCP? How can I tell? Just need it to act as an actual Router is anyone can help. I'm considering using VYOS instead. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: What's your subnet mask?  If you're setting it to 255.0.0.0, then all your subnets will be able to communicate.

Comment: The subnet for all networks are 255.255.255.0.  I still can't figure out why the DG is not the "Router" itself.

Comment: On the vmnets do you have them set to "connect a host virtual adapter"?  if so, that could be how your VMs are seeing outside their subnet, since they have a path through the host to your home DSL.

Comment: "Conect a host virtual adapter" is not checked. I've given up on Freesco for now and have started using VYOS with more success. I now note however, that one of my VM's has a NIC with Two DG's, one for my ADSL home router (which the other NIc is bridged to) and the VYOS router, I've never seen this before, not sure what's going on here. would anyone know how this happens or give advice on how I can discover this?

Comment: I think I just needed to change the DHCP settings of the Freesco router to give out the Default gateway that I needed it to. Anyway, I've moved to use VYOS which works for the most part of what need(It does get funny with DHCP causing my home DSL router to drop out, I've figured out a workaround for this)